# Wrong table prefix in DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php

Tags: magento2.3

We have moved a Magento 2.3 website from one domain to another, and all is done well.

Bu now when a customer is trying to purchase a order, it comes with a error. And I can se in the exception.log the error, is becuase it looks for the old databse table:

**sinm1.yn6g_sequence_order_1** this should be: **sinm1.yman_sequence_order_1**

The yn6g is the old database prefix.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your app/etc/env.php file for table prefix.

```
'db' => [
    'connection' => [
        'indexer' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'dev15',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'active' => '1',
            'persistent' => NULL
        ],
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'dev15',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ],
    **'table_prefix' => ''**
],
```

It will contain the table prefix. you can remove it and try to access the site and place an order.

Answer (score 1):

I search in the MySQL database and found 16 issues with the old prefix, changed them to the new one... and now I can place a order again.